# Is it possible to check, before I buy an airline ticket, whether the TSA will be able to confirm my identity without normal proof of identity?

Tags: air-travel, tsa, identity-cards

I live in the U.S.A., where we may board a regular commercial passenger flight only with the approval of the T.S.A. Passengers are supposed to bring proof of identity with us, and present it when trying to make our way through the airport and onto a plane. **Normally,** people use a passport or an identification card issued by the Department of Motor Vehicles.

The T.S.A. says on their website that someone without ***normal*** proof of identity can still fly if the T.S.A. can confirm his identity.

[image]

I want to fly, but I don't have the ***normal*** proof of identity. And somehow (because of the coronavirus and the maze of rules and the timing of things) I won't have the ***normal*** proof of identity in time for the trip I'm hoping to take.

Is there any way that I can check, before buying an airline ticket, that the T.S.A. will be able to confirm my identity?

Comment: What evidence of identity will you have?

Comment: notice that the wording on the website implies that you **have** a drivers license or passport, but it just isn't with you right now. This is not the same as not having them.

Comment: The obvious way to confirm identity without a document is to look the traveler up in various government databases. If the OP is in one the TSA is likely to confirm their identity. There may be a problem if the OP has never had any of the items listed at [Identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification).

Comment: I don't think any physical object other than the listed items will help. They are going to ask questions: "collecting information such as your name, current address, and other personal information to confirm your identity". That would let them look you up in databases, if you are in any.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan I wonder what other forms of ID the TSA would ask for. For some purposes other than air travel, people ask for school ID, mail to the home, etc. If the TSA just asks questions and consults a database, it seems possible to do this first, before buying an airline ticket. That might save me a lot of time and money, and allow me to travel to the event in some other way, rather than showing up for a flight I cannot board and missing the event.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan I never had the forms of ID listed on the Identification page you link to.

Comment: Have you seen this TSA web page. It goes into more detail and has a short video: https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2018/08/02/four-tips-remember-when-checking-your-id-airport-security

Comment: Have you ever flown in the US? If so, what forms of ID did you use? Are you a US citizen?

Comment: @jcaron I previously flew only while I was under 18 and with my parents, who had the expected ID cards. I'm wondering if paperwork relating to those flights would be helpful somehow.

Comment: @mkennedy No, I had not seen that page, and I agree that it's informative. But it says that if you "simply do not have an acceptable form of ID, our officers will ask you for two secondary forms of identification," without explaining exactly what those secondary forms should be. Maybe approval in that case is a subjective call that the officers make on the spot?

Comment: See https://www.fodors.com/news/travel-tips/navigating-a-nightmare-how-to-get-through-tsa-without-an-id apparently anything can be used, as long as they can corroborate things. Copies of IDs of your parents + birth certificate + pictures of all of you together + school ID + credit or debit card + access to your social network accounts + a few hours early at the airport would be a good start.

Comment: I found a story from a seasoned traveler who'd forgotten his wallet so had absolutely no form of ID at all. He had to fill out a form (name, address, probably SS#, etc.) and TSA called a 3rd party company. He was asked a few questioned that satisfied everyone that he was who he said he was. Probably similar to confirming ID for credit report agency--they ask questions about your accounts or past addresses.

Comment: One secondary form of ID is credit cards. Do you have one?  I believe one way of checking identity is to verify information retrieved from one or more credit bureaus.  This is what happened when my wife, whose driver's license is foreign, forgot her passport for a domestic flight.  I don't remember her filling out a form, but otherwise @mkennedy's comment agrees with her experience.  In her case, though, she did have her wallet, including credit cards and her work ID, which they gave little weight to, but they didn't dismiss it outright as they did her foreign driver's license.

Comment: If you don't drive, it's usually possible to get a non-driver identification card from the state you live in, for a small fee.  I'm not sure _where_ you get one, but it wouldn't surprise me if driver's license offices can also issue non-driver ID cards.

Comment: @Kyralessa The Department of Motor Vehicles requires the same sorts of documentation from an applicant for either a driver's license or another identification card. My problem wasn't passing the driving test, it was producing the needed documentation of my identity.

Comment: The only way is for you to speak with TSA agents at your local airport before your trip. I do not think it is possible to know beforehand if TSA will approve your identity or not and you have not provided enough information to determine whether TSA could.

Comment: If you don't have any identity documents at all (it happens), there are established processes on how to recover them - in the hardest cases this could include going to court: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2015/03/12/how-a-teenagers-viral-campaign-to-prove-her-citizenship-is-inspiring-a-new-texas-bill/. But either way its possible.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue a few years ago. While there no way to confirm you'll be able to pass the verification process, it is unlikely you will fail. In my case, I was asked questions like "what street in closest to where you live?", and they gave me 4 options to choose from.